Good exercise selection from "Understanding Analysis", 2nd edition by Stephen Abbott
I want to learn real analysis using the textbook "Understanding Analysis", 2nd Edition, by Stephen Abbott. My issue is, however, that I can't decide which exercises to do. Doing all of them is not an option for me, since i simply can't afford the time it would take to do all of them. I've looked at a few courses by US-based universities, which base their courses on this book, like these here:

https://users.math.msu.edu/users/chamatth/320spring19.html,
https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/Fa2010-241/, or
https://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Math313.html.

Can anyone else give me a recommendation on what exercises to select, or point me to ressources where such a selection has been made? I am self-studying, btw, so i don't have an instructor who could help me with this.
Thanks in advance.
